# Can´t pass List as parameter to p:commandButton using p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Someone help please...
I am trying to pass a `list` as parameter to a `p:commandButton` inside a `p:dataTable`. It is always `null`.

What is wrong with this?
Thanks in advance!

The Screen components:

```
<h:form id="form-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="">
        <h:outputText value="Foram encontradas as seguintes restrições:" />
        <br /> <br />

        <p:dataTable var="restricao" id="listaRestricoes"
                     value="#{decompDecisaoRestricoesController.listView}">
            <p:inputText value="#{restricao.id}" type="hidden" />
                            
            <p:column headerText="Restrição">
                <h:outputText value="#{restricao.nome}" />
                                
                <p:selectOneRadio id="comentar"
                                  value="#{restricao.comentar}" layout="custom">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="sim" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="nao" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Comentar">
                <p:radioButton for="comentar" itemIndex="0" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Descomentar">
                <p:radioButton for="comentar" itemIndex="1" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </div>
    <div class="button-group">
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-e"
                         value="Executar" widgetVar="uploadButton" 
                         action="#{decompDecisaoRestricoesController.chamaService(listaRestricoes)}" />
    </div>
</h:form>
```

The Controller:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DecompDecisaoRestricoesController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6252355181831338279L;

    @Inject
    private DecompDecisaoRestricoesService service;

    private List<RestricaoDecomp> listView;

    public List<RestricaoDecomp> getListView() {
        return listView;
    }

    public void setListView(List<RestricaoDecomp> listView) {
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    public void onLoad() {
        listView = service.listaRestricoesBanco();
    }

    public void chamaService(List<RestricaoDecomp> lista) {
        service.executar(lista);
    }

}
```

And the Service:

```
@Stateless
public class DecompDecisaoRestricoesService {

    @Inject
    RestricaoDecompDAO restricaoDecompDAO;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void executar(List<RestricaoDecomp> lista) {
        for (RestricaoDecomp restricao : lista) {
            logger.info("NOME: " + restricao.getNome());
            logger.info("COMENTAR:  " + restricao.getComentar());
        }
    }

    public List<RestricaoDecomp> listaRestricoesBanco() {
        List<RestricaoDecomp> lista = new ArrayList<RestricaoDecomp>();
        lista = restricaoDecompDAO.listAll();
        return lista;
    }

}
```

When rendering, the list is displayed in the View. But on submit, it just sends `null`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it!
The bean was `RequestScoped`, so, after the request, it just throwed away the list values.

Changed it to `ViewScoped` and voilá! The list value was there after submission, with the changes the fields.

After that, I just cleaned the `view` after submit. Like this:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-e" onsuccess="window.location.reload(); ..."
```

=)